# Pasar datos de una tabla a un formulario php

Tags: php

Buenas, quiero pasar los datos que aparecen en mi tabla a un formulario en otra página, ¿Cómo lo hago con solo php? El código que tengo es:

```
<?php 
include('conexion.php');
include('busqueda.php');

$busqueda = $_GET['buscar'];
$query = "select * from datos where nombre like '%$busqueda%'";
$consulta = pg_query($conexion, $query);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Resultados </title>
    <style>
        table tr td{
            text-align: center;

        }
        table{
            width: 80%;
            margin-top: 10%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <form method="POST">
        <table border="3">
            <tr>
                <td> ID </td>
                <td> Nombre </td>
                <td> Cedula </td>
                <td> Curso </td>
                <td> Fecha de inicio </td>
                <td> Fecha de culminación </td>
            </tr>
        <?php while($fila = pg_fetch_assoc($consulta)){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td> <?php echo $fila['id']; ?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $fila['nombre']; ?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $fila['cedula']; ?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $fila['curso']; ?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $fila['inicio']; ?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $fila['fin']; ?> </td>
                <td> <input type="submit" name="boton" value="Ver"> </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Cuando le de al input "Ver", para que me envio justo los datos de ese sección de la tabla al formulario en otra página.

Comment: Por lo que veo sin ver mucho detalle de la conexión y si funciona o no tu query la implementación está bien, ¿Te manda algún error la consola o no te arroja datos tu consulta, o si estás mandando correctamente la información que enviaste desde tu forma?

Comment: no me envia la informacion a el formulario que ya cree

Comment: Entonces necesitas regresar a tu formulario y ver cómo le estás enviando la información a tu tabla.

Comment: ¿No necesitas volver al anterior formulario una vez haz pasado los datos? Lo digo porque puedes tener y actualizar el 2º formulario en la misma página del 1º usando Ajax. Por otra parte, tu consulta a la BD es **riesgosa**, ya que no está protegida contra la [**Inyección SQL**](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: También puedes usar jquery y ajax

Comment: perdon se que este tema es pasado estoy tomando el ejemplo del mismo ya acomode todos mis inputs hidden pero cuando en la tabla me aparecen mas de un resultado al seleccionar cualquiera solo me guarda el ultimo ingresado en la tabla no se si me explico por ejemplo me aparecen tres resultados de esos tres resultados selecciono cualquiera y solo se guarda uno solo sin importar cual haya seleccionado

Comment: @vickmt no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, seria mejor que crearas una pregunta, en la cual puedas adjuntar el codigo que utilizas para asi ayudarte en caso de tener algun error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes añadir dichas variables a inputs con la propiedad `hidden`, de esta manera se encontrarán ocultos y cuando pulses en el botón "ver" podrás enviarlos por `POST` a otra página, ejemplo:

```
<form method="POST" action="paginadestino.php">
    <table border="3">
        <tr>
            <td> ID </td>
            <td> Nombre </td>
            <td> Cedula </td>
            <td> Curso </td>
            <td> Fecha de inicio </td>
            <td> Fecha de culminación </td>
        </tr>
    <?php while($fila = pg_fetch_assoc($consulta)){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td> <?php echo $fila['id']; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $fila['nombre']; ?> </td>
            <!--Resto de campos-->

            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $fila['nombre']; ?>">
            <!--Resto de campos-->

            <td> <input type="submit" name="boton" value="Ver"> </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

**No te olvides** de poner la página destino en la propiedad `action` del formulario.

En la página destino recibirías los campos de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php 
    $id = $_POST['id']; 
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    //Resto de campos...
?>
```

Y podrías añadirlos a inputs de un nuevo formulario de la siguiente forma:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
   <input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre; ?>">
   <!-- Resto de campos !-->
</form>
```

También podrías almacenar dichas variables en sesión, de esta manera persistirían entre página y página:

```
<?php
 while($fila = pg_fetch_assoc($consulta)){ 
     $_SESSION['nombre'] = $fila['nombre'];
     // Resto de campos ...
 }
?>
```

Comment: con el input hidden me funciona, pero cuando la tabla me muestra mas de un resultado, siempre me muestra los ultimos datos en el formulario al que envio, no muestra los que selecciono

Comment: Te he puesto un ejemplo simplificado, para que mande todos los campos de la tabla tendrás que poner tantos inputs como campos tengas, obviamente.

Comment: hola me podrías pasar el código completo por favor

Answer (score 2):

Sumándome al comentario anterior lo puedes hacer es con un foreach llenar los datos de la tabla y colocar un contador, es decir por cada fila sumara un numero y ese numero se lo asocias al input de la siguiente manera

```
<form method="POST" action="paginadestino.php">
    <table border="3">
        <tr>
            <td> ID </td>
            <td> Nombre </td>
            <td> Cedula </td>
            <td> Curso </td>
            <td> Fecha de inicio </td>
            <td> Fecha de culminación </td>
        </tr>
    <?php $contador = 1;
          foreach($consulta as $fila){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td> <?php echo $fila['id']; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $fila['nombre']; ?> </td>
            <!--Resto de campos-->

            <input type="hidden" name="id_.''.<?php echo $contador; ?>" value="<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="nombre_.''.<?php echo $contador; ?>" value="<?php echo $fila['nombre']; ?>">
            <!--Resto de campos-->

            <td> <input type="submit" name="boton" value="Ver"> </td>
        </tr>
    <?php $contador = $contador + 1; } ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

que es lo que hace el codigo, es asociarle un name distinto al input asi si tienes mas de una fila cuando la envies los campos seran distintos porque el problema que te ocurre al tener mas de una fila y teniendo el mismo nombre el dato se pisa

espero haber ayudado